# Sagemath simplification

Tags: symbolic-math, sage, simplify

I am interested in expressions like

```
w=2*cos(3/7*pi) - 2*cos(2/7*pi) + 2*cos(1/7*pi) - 1
```

w is exactly 0, as is easily verified by expressing each cosine as sum of powers of a 7'th root of -1; Sage can verify this approximately by evaluating w as real.

I have tried to apply all simplify methods to w, to no avail.  All return the same expression.  Have I reached a Sage limitation, or is there some way of making it handle such expression?

I am using version 8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to know if the expression is zero is to ask.

Typing `w == 0` will return a symbolic equation, but using `bool`
can evaluate it to a boolean.

```
sage: w = 2*cos(3/7*pi) - 2*cos(2/7*pi) + 2*cos(1/7*pi) - 1
sage: w == 0
2*cos(3/7*pi) - 2*cos(2/7*pi) + 2*cos(1/7*pi) - 1 == 0
sage: bool(w == 0)
True
```

Another way is to convert `w` to the field of algebraic numbers, `QQbar`.

```
sage: ww = QQbar(w)
sage: ww
0
```

Note: a similar question was asked and answered as

- [Ask Sage question 45674: Checking that symbolic expression is zero](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/45674)

Comment: Thanks, it helps some, although it can fail.  Here is the result of QQbar(w), where w is a self-conjugate integer linear combination of roots of unity:

Comment: Thanks, it helps some, although it can fail.  Here is the result of QQbar(w), where w is another self-conjugate 6 term integer linear combination of 8th roots of unity: 68.941125496954281171240529381 + 9.4039548065783000637498922978e-38*I  (using 100 bits precision).  The imaginary part is really tiny, but nonzero.  My current hack is to take the real part, but I would like sage itself to recognize the number as real.

Comment: How is `w` produced, and how is the numerical value obtained?

Comment: Start with the Vandermonde matrix corresponding to the n-th roots of unity.  That is, position j,k is $\omega^{jk}$, where $\omega$ is a primitive root. Now, divide rows and columns at the middle (with a proviso to handle parity) and take the NW corner. Finally, take the real part of that matrix (or just add it to its conjugate, so you stay cyclotomic).  I want to solve linear systems $Ax=b$ where $A$ is the matrix I just described. At the end of the day, they are rational, self-conjugate combinations of roots of unity, hence real. Now, hit them with the QQbar hammer.

Comment: Thanks for the mathematical description. Would you also provide your code?